# (Eclipse RCP) How can I add shortcut text after a menu entry in toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp

I want to add shortcut text after the menu entry in toolbar.

For example, for "copy" menu entry in toolbar, default only a image in toolbar, and the tooltips will be "Copy (Ctrl+C)", what I need is adding "Ctrl + C" after the image of Copy menu entry, I did a lots of search, but can't find more useful material.

Also the action ( such as Copy ) has a shortcut, for example, "Ctrl + C", when our mouse hovers on the menu entry, will show "Copy (Ctrl+C)", but when I use Action.getText(), I only can get "Copy", not "Copy (Ctrl + C)"

Thanks for your help, this issue troubled me couple days.

Comment: Now some menu items from toolbar are added in method "fillCoolBar", and others are added from plugin.xml Extensions page.

Answer (score 0):

You can show shortcut easily by using command, action and binding.

First. Create command in org.eclipse.ui.commands extension.
second, Bind shortcut and command in org.eclipse.ui.bindings extension.

If you do that, shortcut(ctrl+c) will be appeared after the command name.

There are helpful article to see tutorial:

How to make command: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html

Key binding: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html

It looks strange and difficult but if you master eclipse command, it will be one of the most powerful extension in RCP development.